# Difference in pronunciation: "cookie" and "kooky"

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

Is there any audible difference between this two words? Google Translate provides very similar transcriptions for them:

cookie - `ˈko͝okē`
kooky - `ˈko͞okē`

Comment: Minimal difference in English. In IPA: /'kʊ ki:/,/'ku: ki:/, or the vowel of 'book','look','hook,'rook' and respectively that of 'loop', 'choose', 'tube'.

Comment: Frankly, mispronunciation of those can signal non-native speaker to a native speaker (in AmE).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqL7jyrXhLs

Comment: For Kookie, listen to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MT9QZBGyXjU

Comment: @GregLee - Darn!  I was about to post that!

Comment: Just to confuse things -- Sesame Street's *Cookie Monster* calls his favorite snack 'kookies'.

Comment: It should be noted that the terms have a wide applicability and varied implications once you get beyond the baked confection.  Several variations of "cookie" have been used, particularly in the military, as a nick-name for "cook", and, similarly, variations of "cookie" are used as a term of affection with roughly the same meaning as "sweetie".  The use of "kookie" (or "kooky") to mean "acting like a kook" is idiomatic but far from the only use of the term.  And, of course, the specific implication of the term colors its pronunciation.

Comment: @Lambie, what is *AmE*?

Comment: Noted baked goods expert Cookie Monster says both words the same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  *Cook* rhymes with *book*, and *kook* rhymes with *Duke*.

Comment: *kook* does not rhyme with *Duke*, more like with *souk*. The word *pewk* ryhmes with *Duke*.

Comment: @WeatherVane: most speakers hear the "u" sound as a rhyme for "oo": the difference is just that "u" has a /j/ glide at the start. So "you" and "u" are homophones, for example.

Comment: I think "spook" is a better rhyme for it.

Comment: @MishaR, [Vic Mizzy](http://addamsfamily.wikia.com/wiki/The_Addams_Family:_Main_Theme) would probably have agreed with you.

Comment: @WeatherVane, American vernacular pronunciation of *Duke* is different than English.  In England *Duke* rhymes with *rebuke*, in the US it usually sounds like  [*Gene Chandler*'s 1962 hit *Duke of Earl*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6Uht69h8Is).

Answer (score 3):

The 'oo' in cookie sounds the same as the 'oo' in book, while the 'oo' in kooky sounds the same as the 'oo' in loony.